# how to add thumbnail into default slider in shopify debut theme?

Tags: jquery, shopify

I am setting up thumbnail into my default slider in shopify debut theme slideshow.liquid section, the default slider is having dots, i want to convert it into`thumbnail images, please help.

I am setting up thumbnail into my default slider in shopify debut theme slideshow.liquid section, the default slider is having dots, i want to convert it into`thumbnail images, please help.

```
  {%- if section.settings.slideshow_height == 'adapt' -%}
  {% comment %}
  'min_aspect_ratio' is the minimum aspect ratio of images shown without
   whitespace when 'slideshow_height' is set to 'adapt'.
    The aspect ratio values for the first image in the slideshow will be 
   used
  unless it is blank, in that case a ratio of 2:1 will be used.
 {% endcomment %}

 {%- assign first_block = section.blocks[0] -%}
 {%- if first_block.settings.image.aspect_ratio == blank -%}
  {%- assign min_aspect_ratio = 2.0 -%}
  {%- else -%}
       {%- assign min_aspect_ratio = 
     first_block.settings.image.aspect_ratio -%}
 {%- endif -%}
 {% assign wrapper_height = 100 | divided_by: min_aspect_ratio %}
 {%- endif -%}

  {%- assign text_alignments = section.settings.text_alignment | split: ' '    -%}
  {%- assign text_horizontal_alignment = text_alignments.first -%}
  {%- assign text_vertical_alignment = text_alignments.last | strip -%}

 <div data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="slideshow- 
 section">
{%- if section.blocks.size > 0 -%}
<div id="SlideshowWrapper-{{ section.id }}" class="slideshow-wrapper" 
role="region" aria-label="slideshow" aria-describedby="slideshow-info" 
  tabindex="-1">
  <div class="slideshow slideshow--{{ section.settings.slideshow_height 
  }}{% if display_controls %} slideshow--display-controls{% endif %}"
       id="Slideshow-{{ section.id }}"
       data-autorotate="{{ section.settings.autorotate }}"
       data-speed="{{ section.settings.autorotate_speed | times: 1000 }}"
       data-adapt-height="{% if section.settings.slideshow_height == 
      'adapt' %}true{% else %}false{% endif %}"
       data-slide-nav-a11y="{{ 'sections.slideshow.load_slide' | t: 
      slide_number: '[slide_number]' }}"
       {% if section.settings.slideshow_height == 'adapt' %}data-min- 
       aspect-ratio="{{ min_aspect_ratio }}"
       style="height: {{- wrapper_height -}}vw"{% endif %}>

    {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
      <div class="slideshow__slide slideshow__slide--{{ block.id }}" {{ 
       block.shopify_attributes }}>
        {% if block.settings.image == blank %}
          <div class="slideshow__image js">
            <div class="placeholder-background">
              {% capture current %}{% cycle 1, 2 %}{% endcapture %}
              {{ 'lifestyle-' | append: current | placeholder_svg_tag: 
             'placeholder-svg' }}
            </div>
            {% if section.settings.show_overlay %}<div 
         class="slideshow__overlay"></div>{% endif %}
          </div>
        {% else %}
          <div class="slideshow__image box ratio-container lazyload{% 
        unless forloop.first %} lazypreload{% endunless %} js"
               data-bgset="{% include 'bgset', image: 
        block.settings.image %}"
               data-sizes="auto"
               data-parent-fit="contain"
               style="background-position: {{ block.settings.alignment 
    }};
                      background-image: url('{{ block.settings.image | 
                img_url: '300x300' }}');">
            {% if section.settings.show_overlay %}<div 
            class="slideshow__overlay"></div>{% endif %}
          </div>
        {% endif %}

        <noscript>
          <div class="slideshow__image"{% if block.settings.image %} 
          style="background-image: url('{{ block.settings.image | 
             img_url: '2048x' }}'); background-position: {{ 
            block.settings.alignment }};"{% endif %}>
            {% if block.settings.image == blank %}
              <div class="placeholder-background">
                {{ 'lifestyle-1' | placeholder_svg_tag: 'placeholder-svg' 
             }}
              </div>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </noscript>

        <div class="slideshow__text-wrap slideshow__text-wrap--desktop">
          <div class="slideshow__text-content slideshow__text-content-- 
            vertical-{{ text_vertical_alignment }} text-{{ 
             text_horizontal_alignment }}">
            <div class="page-width">
              {% unless block.settings.slide_title == blank and 
                  block.settings.subheading == blank %}
                <ul class="slideshow__text-content-list">
                  {%- unless block.settings.slide_title == blank -%}
                    <li>
                      <h2 class="h1 mega-title slideshow__title{% if 
                              section.settings.text_size == 'large' %} 
                      mega-title--large{% endif %}">
                        {{ block.settings.slide_title | escape }}
                      </h2>
                    </li>
                  {%- endunless -%}
                  {%- unless block.settings.subheading == blank -%}
                    <li>
                      <span class="mega-subtitle slideshow__subtitle{% if 
                            section.settings.text_size == 'large' %} 
                           mega-subtitle--large{% endif %}">
                        {{ block.settings.subheading | escape }}
                      </span>
                    </li>
                  {%- endunless -%}
                </ul>
              {% endunless %}

              {%- assign show_link_button = false -%}
              {%- if block.settings.button_label != blank and 
                     block.settings.button_link != blank -%}
                {%- assign show_link_button = true -%}
              {%- endif -%}
              {%- if show_link_button -%}
                <div class="slideshow__btn-wrapper{% if 
                block.settings.slide_title != blank or 
                block.settings.subheading != blank %} slideshow__btn- 
                wrapper--push{% endif %}">
                  <a href="{{ block.settings.button_link }}" class="btn 
                 slideshow__btn">
                    {{ block.settings.button_label | escape }}
                  </a>
                </div>
              {%- endif -%}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
         </div>
        {%- endfor -%}
     </div>

  <div class="slideshow__controls">
    {%- if section.blocks.size > 1 -%}
      {%- assign arrows_width = section.blocks.size | times: 18 | plus: 
      115 -%}

      <div class="slideshow__arrows"
           style="width: {{- arrows_width -}}px">
        <button class="slideshow__arrow slideshow__arrow-left" aria- 
      label="{{ 'sections.slideshow.previous_slide' | t }}">{% include 
         'icon-chevron-left' %}</button>
        <button class="slideshow__arrow slideshow__arrow-right" aria- 
           label="{{ 'sections.slideshow.next_slide' | t }}">{% include 
             'icon-chevron-right' %}</button>
      </div>
      {%- if section.settings.autorotate -%}
        <button type="button" class="slideshow__pause" data-id="{{ 
              section.id }}" aria-live="polite" aria-pressed="false">
          <span class="slideshow__pause-stop">
            {% include 'icon-pause' %}
            <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 
                'sections.slideshow.pause_slideshow' | t }}</span>
          </span>
          <span class="slideshow__pause-rotate">
            {% include 'icon-play' %}
            <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 
              'sections.slideshow.rotate_slideshow' | t }}</span>
          </span>
        </button>
      {%- endif -%}
    {%- endif -%}
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slideshow__text-wrap slideshow__text-wrap--mobile">
  {% if section.blocks.size > 1 %}
    <div class="slideshow__arrows slideshow__arrows--mobile">
      <button class="slideshow__arrow slideshow__arrow-left" aria-label=" 
      {{ 'sections.slideshow.previous_slide' | t }}">{% include 'icon- 
        chevron-left' %}</button>
      <button class="slideshow__arrow slideshow__arrow-right" aria- 
         label="{{ 'sections.slideshow.next_slide' | t }}">{% include 
        'icon-chevron-right' %}</button>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
  {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
    {%- assign show_text = false -%}
    {%- unless block.settings.slide_title == blank and 
      block.settings.subheading == blank -%}
      {%- assign show_text = true -%}
    {%- endunless -%}
    {%- assign show_link_button = false -%}
    {%- if block.settings.button_label != blank and 
        block.settings.button_link != blank -%}
      {%- assign show_link_button = true -%}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- if show_text or show_link_button -%}
      <div class="slideshow__text-content slideshow__text-content--mobile 
       slideshow__text-content--mobile-{{ forloop.index0 }} text-center">
        <div class="page-width">
          {%- unless block.settings.slide_title == blank -%}
            <h2 class="h1 mega-title slideshow__title slideshow__title-- 
             mobile{% if section.settings.text_size == 'large' %} mega- 
           title-- 
          large{% endif %}">
              {{ block.settings.slide_title | escape }}
            </h2>
          {%- endunless -%}
          {%- unless block.settings.subheading == blank -%}
            <span class="mega-subtitle slideshow__subtitle 
          slideshow__subtitle--mobile{% if section.settings.text_size == 
          'large' %} mega-subtitle--large{% endif %}">
              {{ block.settings.subheading | escape }}
            </span>
          {%- endunless -%}

          {%- if show_link_button -%}
            <a href="{{ block.settings.button_link }}" class="btn 
             slideshow__btn slideshow__btn--mobile">
              {{ block.settings.button_label | escape }}
            </a>
           {%- endif -%}
             </div>
           </div>
            {%- endif -%}
         {%- endfor -%}
        </div>
       {%- endif -%}

     {% if section.blocks.size == 0 %}
     <div class="placeholder-noblocks">
    {{ 'homepage.onboarding.no_content' | t }}
       </div>
     {% endif %}
   </div>
```

Comment: Can you specify what code related problems do you have? If you don't know how to implement a thumbnail image in Shopify you will need to read the Liquid documentation: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/image

Answer (score 1):

1. First, you will need to access your themes HTML/CSS. Go to **Online Store > Themes > Actions > Edit Code.**
2. After that, scroll to the Assets folder and select the **theme.js** file.
3. If you are using a Mac, use the cmd + F button to search for this:  **_setActiveThumbnail();**
4. On a new line directly below this add this:  **_initThumbnailSlider();**
5. A few lines before this, look for the **_initBreakpoints: function()** function. Inside this, comment out the first if statement. Then a bit further down inside the unmatch: function() , comment out the if statement there too.
   It should look like this once you are done:
6. Next, go to the Sections area and open the **product-template.liquid** file
7. Look for the  with a class of **thumbnails-wrapper**. This is where the previous/next arrows are, and they are currently set up to only show on mobile.
8. Remove the **medium-up--hide** class from both of these buttons:
9. Now we add a new class **no-clear** to the 



    item that is between the two buttons. If you search for **product-single__thumbnails-item** you can add this class at the end of the line. The **product-template.liquid** file should now look like this when it’s done:
10. Finally, go to the **theme.scss.liquid** file in the Assets section and add the following CSS to the bottom of the file:

Or visit the code in this URL the Css is also here: http://snippet.easimpt.com/topic/details/130

Thanks.